# Simple nested environment problem

Tags: environments

I thought this would be simple, and it may be but I'm missing something. The following (non-functional code) gives this error:

`./mwe-environments.tex:28: LaTeX Error: \begin{innerii} on input line 28 ended by \end{inneri}.`

What am I missing? I'd like `outer` to begin `inneri`, have `innerii` conclude `inner1` and, finally have `\end{outer}` finish `innerii`. (This is a bare-bones MWE -- there is a lot going in in the environments.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{calc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myouter}{}{%
    \begin{inneri}
}{%
    \end{innerii}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{inneri}{}{%
    \bfseries
}{%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerii}{}{%
    \end{inneri}
    \itshape
}{%
%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myouter}
Bla bla bla
\begin{innerii}
BLA bLA bLA
\end{myouter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: anything is possible but it's just wrong to try to make `\begin{innerii}
BLA bLA bLA
\end{myouter}`  be valid it defeats the entire point of the environment syntax with matching named group delimiters.

Comment: What's the purpose of having a `\begin` without the matching `\end`? This seems like an XY question.

Comment: I may be guilty of over-simplifying the issue. The goal was to give the easiest code with the fewest keystrokes to non-TeX users. `\begin{myouter}` starts the formatting, `\begin{innerii}` formats another section and `\end{myouter}` completes the formatting with a touch of *sicut erat in principio* for good measure. I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but having started down that path I was determined to persevere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David says, doing this is not recommended as it breaks the LaTeX `\begin{env}...\end{env}` paradigm that everyone expects. This said, here is another way to fix the issue: rather than using `\begin{inneri}` and `\end{inneri}` inside the environments just use `\inneri` and `\endinneri`. This stops LaTeX from looking ahead and searching for an `\end{inneri}`. The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{calc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myouter}{}{%
    \inneri
}{%
    \end{innerii}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{inneri}{}{%
    \bfseries
}{%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerii}{}{%
    \endinneri
    \itshape
}{%
%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myouter}
Bla bla bla
\begin{innerii}
BLA bLA bLA
\end{myouter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tacky of me to switch solutions, but this is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @sgmoye I don't mind either way but the outputs are different, they don't just remove the error. Andrew's version removes the grouping so the declarations from `\inneri` stay in scope after `\endinneri`

Comment: @sgmoye the worrying thing if you accept either solution is that you might actually use this syntax in a document!

Comment: @sgmoye Some people waut a while before accepting solutions for this reason. Either way you should give David an up-vote.

Comment: @Andrew I have more than enough of those already:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's more the principle. You're right, I should add the grouping back into my solution, using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`,  and echo your words about "don't do this":)

Comment: @Andrew if you put the grouping back you'll reset `\@currenvir` and then the solutions will be the same (latex isn't looking ahead for these environments as it does for newenv based ones)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Curious! Thanks for pointing this out. I knew that `\NewDocumentEnvironment` didn't look ahead but I assume that putting groups in here would be innocuous!

Comment: Again, my apologies. As it happens, Andrew supplied a solution that happens to work perfectly in my environment and I learned something. I also learned something from the answer given by @DavidCarlisle. Thanks to you both. I will curb my enthusiasm (borne this time of desperation/hysteria) in the future.

Comment: @sgmoye no need to apologise

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX is very flexible but if you bend it this much, it might snap, but this runs without error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myouter}{}{%
    \begin{inneri}%
}{%
% please don't do this in any public package
% it completely breaks latex syntax and any editors, syntax
% highlighters or humans trying to read the document.
   \def\@currenvir{innerii}%
    \end{innerii}%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{inneri}{}{%
    \bfseries
}{%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerii}{}{%
% please don't do this in any public package
% it completely breaks latex syntax and any editors, syntax
% highlighters or humans trying to read the document.
    \def\@currenvir{inneri}%
    \end{inneri}%
    \itshape
}{%
%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{myouter}
Bla bla bla
\begin{innerii}
BLA bLA bLA
\end{myouter}

\end{document}
```